# How to find the Jacobian of this transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution, order-statistics, jacobian

Of this transformation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z_1 &= nX_{(1)} 
&&\rightarrow 
&X_{(1)} &= \frac{Z_1}{n} \\
Z_2 &= (n-1)(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}) 
&&\rightarrow 
& X_{(2)} &= \frac{Z_1}{n} + \frac{Z_2}{n-1} \\
&&&\;\;\vdots & \\ 
Z_n &= (X_{(n)} - X_{(n-1)}) 
&&\rightarrow 
&X_{(n)} &= \frac{Z_1}{n} + \frac{Z_2}{n-1}+ \dots + Z_n \\ 
\end{aligned}
$$
Supposing $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \operatorname{iid} \text{ Exp}(1)$ and $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$ are the order statistics. The solution says it is $1/n!$ but I do not really get how if the Jacobian transformation is defined as
$$
f(z) = \biggl\lvert \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \biggr\rvert \, f(x).
$$

Comment: ${\partial x\over\partial z}$ is a lower triangular matrix with diagonal $(1/n,1/(n-1),\dots,1)$, hence, determinant ${1\over n!}$. This calculation has nothing to do with probability, statistics, order-statistics, ....

Comment: Are we OK, alien?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes thanks for the hint, just answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_{(1)}}{\partial z_1} & \frac{\partial x_{(2)}}{\partial z_1} & ... & \frac{\partial x_{(n)}}{\partial z_1} \\
\frac{\partial x_{(1)}}{\partial z_2} & \frac{\partial x_{(2)}}{\partial z_2} & ... & \frac{\partial x_{(n)}}{\partial z_2} \\
\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial x_{(1)}}{\partial z_n} & \frac{\partial x_{(2)}}{\partial z_n} & ... & \frac{\partial x_{(n)}}{\partial z_n} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac1n&\frac1n&...&\frac1n\\
0&\frac{1}{n-1}&...&\frac{1}{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&...&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$|J|=\frac 1n\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}\cdot ... \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{n!}$